# jQuery Slide effect with a background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I came across this slide effect that I wanted to try.  Basically is slides a div over another div with a darkened background. When I hover over theimage...just the border turns dark.  No text is shown over the image or anything.  Can you see if anything looks out of wack??

CSS:

```
#container {
 width:400px;
 height:150px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:0;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-image:url(../images/slide-bg.png);
 border:10px solid #414141;
}

#container:hover {
 border-color:#303030;
}

#overlay {
 background-color:#000;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:400px;
 height:150px;
 z-index:1;
}

#hover {
 width:400px;
 display:block;
 height:100px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:3;
 padding:25px;
 background-color:#1e1e1e;
 padding-top:150px;
 font-size:11px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#hover p {
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:normal;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="overlay">
    </div>
    <div id="hover">
        Some Text here????
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colour = $("#overlay");
    var content = $("#hover");
    content.hide();
    colour.hide();
});

$("#container").hover(function() {
    content.show().css({ "left" : "-400px" }).animate({left : 0}, 300);
    colour.stop().fadeTo(500, .7)
},function() {
    content.animate({left : 400}, 300);
    colour.stop().fadeTo(500, 0)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in your css.. It's because you have

```
padding-top: 150px;
```

which pushes the text way below the box.

I commented it out in the fiddle below and it's showing up.

Also you want to put your .hover code inside the `$(document).ready` function

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/vCe6N/

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery part - from the 7th line the code is outside jQuery onReady - and it uses jQuery.
The rest seems ok.